# Unable to instantiate application

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

ERROR:

```
08-21 00:08:53.544: D/AndroidRuntime(31470): Shutting down VM
08-21 00:08:53.544: W/dalvikvm(31470): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b6a8)
08-21 00:08:53.549: E/AndroidRuntime(31470): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 00:08:53.549: E/AndroidRuntime(31470): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.sg.js.OldMaid.OldMaid: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sg.js.OldMaid.OldMaid in loader 
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.sg.js.OldMaid-1/pkg.apk]
08-21 00:08:53.549: E/AndroidRuntime(31470):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:497)
08-21 00:08:53.549: E/AndroidRuntime(31470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3362)
08-21 00:08:53.549: E/AndroidRuntime(31470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:155)
08-21 00:08:53.549: E/AndroidRuntime(31470):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1037)
08-21 00:08:53.549: E/AndroidRuntime(31470):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
08-21 00:08:53.549: E/AndroidRuntime(31470):    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
08-21 00:08:53.549: E/AndroidRuntime(31470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3820)
08-21 00:08:53.549: E/AndroidRuntime(31470):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 00:08:53.549: E/AndroidRuntime(31470):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
```

Once i run the application.. It automatically force close even though i have check my manifest file.. but maybe i need other eyes to see my mistake

CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="4" android:versionName="1.0.4" package="com.sg.js.OldMaid"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application 
android:allowBackup="true"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:name=".OldMaid"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
<activity 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:name=".OldMaid" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode ">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

This is my Manifest.xml .. check if ever there are some mistakes.

Comment: Is your class name `com.sg.js.OldMaid.OldMaid`? That is, a class named `OldMaid` in a package named `com.sg.js.OldMaid`? BTW please read SO FAQ and improve your question title, the current contains no information

Comment: What does the oldmaid class look like?

Comment: default solution: did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: yes, i have clean it everytime i debug it

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have the class name in the package="..." attribute.  Try removing ".OldMaid" from the end of that attribute.

Comment: If this is the case, shouldn't it throw a compile time error?

Comment: The package name and the Activity class name (from the activity's android:name attribute) are appended as strings to produce the fully qualified name of the class that should be instantiated to start this Activity, but it doesn't check to be sure a class by that name actually exists until run time.  Hence the class not found error.

Comment: I've just tried to simulate, and yes it does compiles. But the Android Studio won't even try to launch the app, giving a `Default Activity not found` error. Intellij IDEA gives just a warning, and I guess  Eclipse doesn't even check for this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem lied in my **module's gradle configuration**!
It **contains a field called** `applicationId` which contains the string value of the package. And this apparently contained the old package name!
I fixed this, and after the gradle sync, everything worked fine!